# Angular 8:mat pagination can not choose page

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot

My mat-paginator in app.component.html:

```
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 15, 30]" [pageSize]="5" [length]="totalElements"
                      (page)="nextPage($event)">

</mat-paginator>
```

app component:

```
  totalElements = 5;

  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
  nextPage(event: PageEvent) {
    const request = {};
    // @ts-ignore
    request.page = event.pageIndex.toString();
    // @ts-ignore
    this.totalElements = request.size = event.pageSize.toString();
    // @ts-ignore
    this.getDevelopers(request);
  }
```

getDevelopers:

```
  public getDevelopers(request: {page: string, size: string}): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.developerService.getAllUsers(request)
      .subscribe(data => {
        // @ts-ignore
        this.users = data.content;
        // @ts-ignore
        this.totalElements = data.totalElements;
        this.loading = false;
      }
  }
```

My controller:

```
    @GetMapping
    @ResponseBody
    @ApiOperation(value = "Get list of all developers")
    public Page<GetByIdDeveloperResponse> getAllDevelopers(
            @RequestParam(name = "page", defaultValue = "0") int page,
            @RequestParam(name = "size", defaultValue = "4") int size,
            @RequestParam(name = "sort_by", defaultValue = "id") String sortBy
    ) {
        Page<GetByIdDeveloperResponse> developers = developerMapper.getDeveloperResponseListFromDeveloperList(developerService.getAllDevelopers(page, size, sortBy));
        return new PageImpl<GetByIdDeveloperResponse>(developers.getContent(), PageRequest.of(page, size), developers.getTotalElements());
    }
```

I can change size of page, but i can't open other page.
< > are not aviable for me
[image]

In postman everything in is ok, but here it doesn't work.

How looks my service method:

```
    public List<Developer> getAllDevelopers(int page, int size, String sortValue) {
        logger.info("Get all developers was called, page: " + page + " size: " + size + " sort by: " + sortValue);
        Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by(sortValue));
        Page<Developer> pagedResult = developerRepository.findAll(paging);
        return pagedResult.getContent();
    }
```

How repository looks:

```
@Repository
public interface DeveloperRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Developer, String> {
    Developer findById(String id);
}
```

How json looks:

[image]

When i am trying to GET .../developers?size=10

I got 10 total elements, i think problem is related to **"totalPages": 1,**
Because even if i get all elements, there will be only 1 page

[image]

Debug:

[image]

Comment: What is the actual call made from Angular client? Did you observe one in browser developer tools? Also it would be useful if you showed `developerService.getAllUsers(request)` implementation (client-side).

Comment: added getAllDevelopers to question.
I tested it in intelij idea.
It send request succesfully, and i get size in my controller and it works.
But problem is with page. I just can not click on this < > buttons. Something wrong with angular code

Comment: @Rostyslav, show us what `getAllDevelopers()` api returns?

Comment: @er-sho i added it to question

Comment: @Rostyslav, the behavior of paginator is as intend because your api returns only 4 total elements and you have mentioned 5 in your code. So whenever your api doesn't return more than 5 elements then you can't get that button (< >) active into your paginator

Comment: @Rostyslav, Jus return more than 5 total elements from api and then rest will work as intend

Comment: @ersho the totalElements is 4 because i have default value in comtroller.
When i am trying to GET .../developers?size=12 there are 12 elements, i updated question with screenshot of it.

Comment: @Rostyslav, So did you get those buttons **< >** active in paginator?

Comment: @er-sho no, even if i get list of all developers, this buttons will be not active

Comment: @er-sho i think problem is related to **"totalPages": 1,**
Because even if i get all elements, there will be only 1 page

Comment: If your `totalPages` value is always 1, show us a repository - it might be a problem with count query

Comment: @SergVasylchak added code of repository before photos

Comment: Hehe, found a reason. `new PageImpl<GetByIdDeveloperResponse>(developers.getContent(), PageRequest.of(page, size), developers.getTotalElements())`. Here `developers.getTotalElements` is always corrupted, because you lose this value in `pagedResult.getContent()` -> you return only the data list and ignore everything else retrieved from the repository Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lose your paged result data (page number, page size, etc.) in your service method when you do `return pagedResult.getContent()`.

Consider the following:

Service method:

```
public Page<Developer> getAllDevelopers(int page, int size, String sortValue) {
    logger.info("Get all developers was called, page: " + page + " size: " + size + " sort by: " + sortValue);
    Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by(sortValue));
    return developerRepository.findAll(paging);
}
```

Controller method:

```
@GetMapping
@ApiOperation(value = "Get list of all developers")
public Page<GetByIdDeveloperResponse> getAllDevelopers(
        @RequestParam(name = "page", defaultValue = "0") int page,
        @RequestParam(name = "size", defaultValue = "4") int size,
        @RequestParam(name = "sort_by", defaultValue = "id") String sortBy
) {
    return this.developerService.getAllDevelopers(page, size, sortBy)
           .map(this.developerMapper::mapToGetByIdDeveloperResponse)
}
```

Comment: Or make a developerMapper implementation which accepts `Page<T>` and returns `Page<R>` copying exactly all of the source Page's properties.